# SED escape special characters

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use SED and change a line in a file:

```
 "homepage": "http://localhost:123/",
```

to

```
 "homepage": "http://localhost:123/newpath",
```

using

```
sed -i "s/^"homepage": "http:\/\/localhost:123\/"/"homepage": "http:\/\/localhost:123\/newpath"/g"
```

But it doesnt work, maybe i forgot to escape?

Edit:
Plus there is another nearly similiar line in the file (which should not be modefied)!

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:123",
```

Comment: You have conflicting quotes....   Try single quotes around your sed expression...

Comment: sed -i 's/^"abc": "http:\/\/localhost:123\/",/"abc": "http:\/\/localhost:123\/newpath",/g' doesnt work either :/

Comment: `sed -i 's|^"abc": "http://localhost:123/",|"abc": "http//localhost:123/newpath",|g' tmp.txt`   (changed delimiter to `|`, so you don't need to escape `/`'s anymore)

Comment: sed -i 's|^"homepage": "http://localhost:123/",|"homepage": "http://localhost:123/newpath",|g' /etc/xyz/package.json

doesnt work either, I'm really confused.
+ I edited the start post, there is a nearly similiar line in the file, but that shouldn't affect your solution normally.

Comment: @Aeris: Hmm. I just saw the edit. I have just updated  my answer to cover your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat 48308267
"homepage": "http://localhost:123/",<br>
"proxy": "http://localhost:123",
$ sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*"homepage"/s#:123/#:123/newpath#' 48308267
# the -i option writes the changes to the file itself
$ cat 48308267
"homepage": "http://localhost:123/newpath",<br>
"proxy": "http://localhost:123",
```

A more generalized version would be to reuse matched patterns

```
$ cat 48308267
"homepage": "http://localhost:123/",<br>
"proxy": "http://localhost:123",
$ sed -iE '/^[[:blank:]]*"homepage"/s#(:[[:digit:]]+/)#\1newpath#' 48308267
$ cat 48308267
"homepage": "http://localhost:123/newpath",<br>
"proxy": "http://localhost:123",
```

<sup>**Note:** The general version would work for any port number, not just `123`</sup>

---

You have the leverage to change the delimiter of the `s` command from the default `/` to virtually anything that doesn't conflict with the pattern.

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Comment: I believe `:number/` pattern is sure representaion of a port in the file. You can have finer patterns anyways. `:-)`

Comment: Wow thanks!
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*"homepage"/s#:123/#:123/newpath#' 48308267
did it!

I'm really bad at using SED, but this solution is out of my knowledge to be honest.

Thank you very much I've learned a new trick today :)

Comment: @Aeris : You're welcome. Glad that you've learned something new too.. Consider reading a good tutorial about `sed` `:-)`

Comment: after using it he shows me the output with the newpath, but doesnt save it into the file :O

And I will read a book about SED soon, it's already ordered, since my SED knowledge is very very basic :D

Comment: To save the changes file, you could use the inplace edit option of the `sed`. See the edit, I have made just now.

Comment: You saved my day thanks! :)
And i really have a book to read on my weekend :O

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '"abc": "http://localhost:123/",<br>' | \
  sed 's|"abc": "http://localhost:123/",<br>|"abc": "http://localhost:123/newpath",|'
```

---

`sed` accepts other delimiters, like `:`, `|`, etc.; not only `/`.

Comment: the op says `use sed and change a line in a file:` So you need not worry about  single quoting the `echo` stuff. :) But the underlying idea is right. :-)

Comment: @sjsam Not sure what you mean. This is imo the only correct answer

Comment: @hek2mgl : The pattern as such is inside a file as mentioned in the first line of the question. So why need `echo` here?

Comment: @sjsam: i understand that op knows `sed`, knows how to `sed` a file; he is only a bit confused about double quotes, slashes,...; so I just give an example how to make it work in the way he needs

Answer (score 0):

Following simple `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed 's/",$/newpath",/g'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"abc": "http://localhost:123/newpath",
```

If you are happy with above code's output into same Input_file itself then add `-i` option with `sed` too.

Comment: How realistic is it that the input file contains only a single `",` ? If you agree that this is very unrealistic, what is the worth of this answer then?

Comment: I can't follow this argumentation.

Comment: @hek2mgl, apologies. I meant that code was given as per OP's shown sample. In case OP says real file don't have ", it or could have multiple of it. I could try some other approach too on same. Please let me know your thoughts on same.

Comment: I edited the start post, I forgot to mention that there is 1 line, which is nearly similiar in the file.